# React app is failing to compile, it appears typescript not being transpiled to JS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a react app with a couple of colleagues, and after the latest pull I am no longer able to compile the app, but my colleagues are not having any issues.

On my end the app fails to compile because some @material-ui components are displayed as missing in the node_modules/@material-ui directory. However, when I search the folder, I see the files there, they are just shown in typescript format instead of js. However, when comparing my working directory with a colleague's it appears there are also files completely missing on my end that exists on theirs.

For example, when the app fails to compile I see this:

> Failed to Compile
>
> ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/TextField/TextField.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve '../FilledInput' in
> '..../node_modules/@material-ui/core/TextField'

When I search this folder, the file is there but labelled 'FilledInput.d.ts'.

Has anyone encountered something like this?  I have recompiled the app, and deleted the branch and recloned from remote but the issue remains.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing node_modules and installing dependencies again?

Does npm install give any peer dependency warnings? Does this help?

```
npm i @material-ui/core --save
```

Comment: Have your colleaques tried that? Maybe they installed a node module witthout saving it to package.json?